# Why is phosphorous acid diprotic and not triprotic?

Tags: acid-base

In H3PO3 only only 2 hydroxide groups exist, instead of 3. If there is 3 hydroxide group, the phosphorous will have 1 lone pair electrons, which will still satisfy the valence electron of Phosphorous.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44210/structure-of-h3po3

Answer (score 3):

The two isomers you're referring to both exist and are in equilibrium:

[image]

When only one or two protons are removed, resonance stabilizes the anions formed, e.g. the $\ce{HPHO3^-}$ anion:

[image]

The trianion (shown below) doesn't have the benefit of resonance stabilization. This makes removing the third proton much harder.

[image]