# What will be the preferred reaction between phosphorous acid (H3PO3) and potassium hydroxide (KOH)

Tags: acid-base

""To neutralize completely $\pu{20 mL}$ of $\pu{0.1 M}$ aqueous solution of phosphorus $\ce{H3PO3}$ acid the volume of $\pu{0.1 M}$ aqueous $\ce{KOH}$ solution required is: ____""

To solve this question a source used the reaction:
$$\ce{H3PO3 + 2 KOH -> K2HPO3 + 2 H2O}$$

While other source used the reaction
$$\ce{H3PO3 + 3 KOH -> K3PO3 + 3 H2O}$$

I know that $\ce{H3PO3}$ is dibasic. So I thought definitely two $\ce{H+}$ will get replaced by $\ce{K}$ atoms (As shown in the 1st reaction). But later I learnt that if $\ce{KOH}$ is in excess, then $\ce{H3PO3}$ will react with $\ce{KOH}$ to produce $\ce{K3PO3}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. However, if $\ce{KOH}$ is limited, then $\ce{H3PO3}$ will react with $\ce{KOH}$ to produce $\ce{K2HPO3}$ and $\ce{H2O}$.

So, my question that arose was do we take $\ce{KOH}$ as excess when we solve questions like this or do we take a limited value?

Edit:The 2nd reaction in the question does not take place as described in the accepted answer

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It is a phosphite. The last H is not acidic.

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry I clarified what I meant to ask.I think now one will be able to understand what I meant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is phosphorous acid diprotic and not triprotic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47794/why-is-phosphorous-acid-diprotic-and-not-triprotic)

Comment: Hello @Mithoron .Thanks for your reply but sorry my question was not why phosphorous acid is diprotic.My question was do we take NaOH in excess or in limited while we solve questions like that

Comment: Chem+Math formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Provide the source that talks about formation of $\ce{K3PO3}$.

Comment: @Poutnik Please see the production part in this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripotassium_phosphate. Edit Sorry I overlooked that it is tripotassium phosphate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phosphorous acid $\ce{H3PO3}$ is not an ordinary acid. It has extremely unusual reactions.

First, although it has three $\ce{H}$  atoms, only two are related to oxygen atoms, and only these two $\ce{H}$ atoms can be replaced by metallic atoms like $\ce{K}$ or $\ce{Na}$. The third $\ce{H}$ atom is related directly to the central phosphorus atom, and cannot be replaced by alcaline atoms. The acid structure is probably better described by $\ce{HPO(OH)2}$ or $\ce{H2[HPO3]}$. So its neutralization by $\ce{NaOH}$ occurs through one of the two following reactions : $$\ce{H3PO3 + NaOH -> NaH2PO3 + H2O}$$ $$\ce{H3PO3 + 2 NaOH -> Na2HPO3 + 2 H2O}$$ These two sodium salts should be better described as :

$\ce{Na[H(PO)(OH)O]}$ or $\ce{NaH[HPO3]}$ instead of $\ce{NaH2PO3}$

$\ce{Na2[H(PO)O2]}$ or $\ce{Na2[HPO3]}$ instead of $\ce{Na2HPO3}$

The "expected" third salt $\ce{Na3PO3}$ is never produced by neutralization and does not exist.

Second, the acid and its salt have strong reducing properties. For example they reduce $\ce{Hg^{2+} and Ag+}$ ions into the corresponding metal : $$\ce{H3PO3 + 2 Ag+ + H2O -> 2 Ag + H3PO4 + 2 H+}$$

Phosphorous acid has the specific property of reducing sulfur dioxide in solution into elementary sulfur at room temperature : $$\ce{2H3PO3 + SO2 -> 2H3PO4 + S}$$

Comment: I learnt that if NaOH is in excess, then H3PO3 will react with NaOH to produce Na3PO3 and H2O.However, if NaOH is limited, then H3PO3 will react with NaOH to produce Na2HPO3 and H2O.Is this correct? @Maurice

Comment: No. The third $\ce{H}$ atom of $\ce{H3PO3}$ is not able to react with a hydroxyde, in excess or not, whatever the circumstances.  To be able to react with $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{KOH}$, the $\ce{H}$ atom has to be bound to an oxygen atom. This third $\ce{H}$ atom is not bound to an oxygen atom. So it does not react as an acid. In the similar molecule $\ce{PH3}$, the $\ce{H}$ atoms don't react with hydroxides, even in great excess.

Comment: Please see the production part in this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripotassium_phosphate @Maurice

Comment: @Rajesh Paul. Your reference is related to tripotassium phosphate $\ce{K3PO4}$ which exists. But this well-known phosphate has nothing to do with derivates of phosphorous acid $\ce{H3PO3}$. There are $4$ oxygen atoms in tripotassium phosphate, and not $3$ like in derivates of phosphorous acid.  $\ce{H3PO3}$ ≠ $\ce{H3PO4}$ !

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that.You are absolutely correct

Comment: Technical note: do not use references to mobile versions of Wikipedia pages. If posting it from a phone, modify `en.m.wikipedia.org` to `en.wikipedia.org`